# React Client Side rendering load data with fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am still new to React and I am trying to figure out how to combine the Client Side and Server Side rendering. At the moment I am fetching data with node.js while using Client Side rendering, which looks like this:

```
const path    = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ data: 'test' });
});
```

And in the component Class:

```
class Add extends React.Component {
state = {
    data: ''
}

componentDidMount()
{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/add')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            data: response.data
        }));
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}

render()
{
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{this.state.data}</p>
        </div>
    );
}  
}
```

So when I go to the /add Route `(http://localhost:3000/add)`, while using Client Side rendering, the JSON data does get fetched and shown in the `<p>` tag. But when I refresh the page, or manually enter /add in the URL, all that is shown is the raw JSON output on the screen, without loading any components.

How can I show the fetched data in the `<p>` if she user refreshes or manually goes to the /add Route? Any tips how I could make this work better are welcome.

Here I have set the historyApiFallback for Client Side rendering:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Routing:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/add" component={Add} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: You need to have a catch all route in your express server that serves the same content regardless of path.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson do you mean I must add a `app.get('*')`? If i do this then the data does not get fetched at all, the refresh will work tho, but no data will be shown

Comment: Yes, that correct - on that `*` you'll serve the app. Under the same app you would need to render the entire react application and serve it as a rendered HTML file. This way when your app is being rendered it'll call the necessary endpoints to fetch the data. You need to put the `*` at the end. This is a HUGE question and not one that is easily answered using the Q&A format of Stackoverflow unfortunately :(

Comment: I see, i didn't know I had to do this. So I googled about what you said, and found a tutorial, I'll try that, it's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the tip